# Resolving singularities via blowups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a singular affine variety over a field $k$. I have learned that we can obtain a resolution of singularities (i.e. a nonsingular variety $W$ and a proper birational morphism $W \to X$) by blowing up singular points of $X$. For simplicity's sake let's say $X$ is a curve in the affine plane $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\CC$ and $X$ is singular only at the origin, and furthermore the resolution is obtained by blowing up once. Then blowing up the the affine plane at the origin and taking the preimage of the curve $X$ in this blow up should be our resolution, which is some subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{PP}^1$. Here is my point of confusion. The resolution $V$ has two affine charts, but many of the examples I have seen of this procedure seem to speak as if a single affine chart IS the desired resolution. Certainly the pictures are nicer to draw if one works in a single affine chart, but I don't see why the map will be proper if one only uses a single chart.

Comment: If you're clever about your coordinates, you can arrange your blowup so all the points are in one chart, and then just use that chart.

Comment: There is also the matter of people often just being interested in what happens at the singular point, and only working out enough charts to see that.

Answer (score 1):

Take for instance the curve $xy=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ if you blow up the origin using the usual coordinates, you will need both charts to draw it. But as they have told you can pick one. The reason why it is because in each chart you are missing one point of the exceptional divisor (in this case) and by changing coordinates you can assume that this point does not belong to the tangent cone.